# Помогите с RecyclerView и SqLite

Tags: android, sqlite, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Нужно заполнить элементы `RecyclerView` из `SQlite`.. 
Как реализовать не знаю.
Какой `adapter` использовать? если ткнет кто носом буду весьма признателен!

Не знаю как связать `RecyclerView.Adapter` с бд.

**Adapter:**

```
public class RecycleAdapterNou extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapterNou.NounsViewHolder> {





    public static class NounsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cardView;
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
        public NounsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        }
    }
    List<Noun> list;

    public RecycleAdapterNou(List<Noun> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public NounsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);
        NounsViewHolder holder = new NounsViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NounsViewHolder holder, int i) {

        holder.text1.setText(list.get(i).name);
        holder.text2.setText(list.get(i).transcr);
        holder.text3.setText(list.get(i).transla);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если речь идет о SQLite, то почему в адаптер передается List а не Cursor? Это [очень плохое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809767/177345). Лучшим вариантом будет [использование Room + support.v7.ListAdapter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806498/177345), которые имеют вжные преимущества, но если есть готовая SQL база, с которой необходимо работать, то можно использовать [сторонние адаптеры для RecyclerView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/760367/177345), которые работают с курсором напрямую