# Список RecyclerView и данные из SQLite

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Решила написать небольшое приложение-справочник лекарств.

Создала базу с таблицей `test_db` и полями: `_id, title, category, text`.

Для вывода на экран решила использовать `RecyclerView`. Для вывода данных из БД и список нашла адаптер, который выгружает данные в коллекцию, а из коллекции уже в `RecyclerView`.

А есть ли возможность работать напрямую с базой, без коллекций? Прошу вас помочь. Если можете оформите в виде ответа. Спасибо.

Готового примера я не нашла.

Answer (score 4):

Это уже тянет на FAQ :)

Мне не лень, повторюсь еще раз: к сожалению в `RecyclerView` отсутствует адаптер, который умеет работать с записями БД (как например `CursorAdapter` в `ListView`)

К счастью умные люди уже написали [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter) - то есть адаптер, на который подается `Cursor` и он умеет правильно с ним работать.

Comment: Еще я нашла такую штуку https://skillberg.com/courses/android/lessons/loaders-cursorloader-rabotaem-s-contentprovider-ispolzuya-zagruzchiki/  это тоже самое что вы дали?

Comment: Ну в общем то да - это то же самое

Comment: Поняла. Спасибо. Буду тогда разбираться

Comment: В смысле не умеет? 
Конкретно я недавно использовал адаптер для recyclerview, который работает с БД Realm и работает напрямую со списком записей из таблицы: RealmResults<ClassName> list...

Comment: Речь шла об адаптере над `Cursor`. `Realm` не показывает наружу никакой курсор, показывая уже готовые списки, которые конечно же можно засунуть в адаптер