# вывести информацию из базы данных в listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

в активности ActivityList при нажатии на кнопку b1 должно происходить добавление информации из базы данных в listview. Однако, информация добавляется только при повторном входе в данную активность, а не при нажатии на кнопку b1. 
Код активности

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class ActivityList extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtListView;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button b3;
    EditText eT;
    ListView listView;
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db_sort;
    long userId=0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        txtListView = findViewById(R.id.txtListView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String outputString = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        txtListView.setText(outputString);
        databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        listView=findViewById(R.id.List);
        eT=findViewById(R.id.eT);

        //создаём БД
       databaseHelper.create_db();
    }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
// открываем подключение
    db_sort = databaseHelper.open();
    //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
    userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);

    // определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
    String[] headers = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
    // создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
    userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, eT.getText().toString());
            db_sort.update(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userId),  null);
            db_sort.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
        }

    });
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db_sort.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
        }
    });
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                databaseHelper.close();
                userCursor.close();
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
}       }
```

Код базы данных

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

//import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    static String DB_NAME = "AESDataBase.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private Context myContext;

    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath()+DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput;
        OutputStream myOutput;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
     SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: необходимо обновить данные адаптера `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: @Jarvis_J на SimpleCursorAdapter метод notifyDataSetChanged() не действует, нужно свапнуть курсор, чтобы обновить список

Answer (score 2):

Добавление данных происходит как надо, но вы не обновляете информацию из БД, чтобы изменения появились на экране. Для этого надо повторно прочитать данные из БД и обновить список, свапнув старый `Cursor`:

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, eT.getText().toString());
        db_sort.update(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userId),  null);
        db_sort.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
        userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);
        userAdapter.swapCursor(userCursor);
    }
```

Нельзя не заметить, что вы используете приемы прошлого века и сейчас технологии шагнули далеко вперед. С появлением в библиотеке поддержки версии 27.1.0 класса [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html) весь процесс взаимодействия БД и виджетов полностью автоматизирован и даже анимирован с минимальным количеством клиентского кода.

Сегодня использование связки: *Room - LiveData - ViewModel - support.v7.ListAdapter* дает следующие преимущества:

1. любые изменения в БД (удаление\вставка\изменение) автоматически попадают в `LiveData`, которая подписывается на эти изменения.
2. `ListAdapter` же подписывается на `LiveData` и автоматически обновляет виджет `RecyclerView`в соответствии с актуальными данными в БД
3. интегрированная в `ListAdapter` имплементация `DiffUtil` заботится о нужных для отображения изменений действиях в списке и анимирует их
4. о корректном взаимодействии с жизненным циклом активити заботится `ViewModel` и вам не придется переживать о восстановлении данных при поворотах устройства
5. ORM `Room` существенно упростит взаимодействие с реляционной БД и представит табличные данные в виде объектов.