# Android. Два фрагмента с ListVIew

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Добрый день. Имеется приложение, в котором есть 2 фрагмента содержащие `ListView`. При помощи `CursorLoader` списки заполняются данными из двух разных таблиц. В первом фрагменте вызывается диалог с кнопкой, нажатие на которую приводит к удалению из первой таблицы и добавлению во вторую. Как при нажатии на эту кнопку сразу обновлять `ListView` во втором фрагменте? Возможно ли реализовать так, чтобы имплементировать интерфейс `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` требовалось только в `MainActivity`, а не в обоих фрагментах?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    }

    public void addTask(View view) {
        createAddTaskDialog();
    }

    public void finishTask(View view) {
        System.out.println("finish");
    }

    private void createAddTaskDialog() {
        /*код создания AlertDialog*/
        ...

        addDialog.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               /*реализация добавления в БД*/
               ...

                getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
            }
        });
        addDialog.show();
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return FragmentCurrentTask.newInstance();

            if (position == 1)
                return FragmentFinishedTask.newInstance();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Код первого фрагмента (второй полностью аналогичен, только берет данные из другой таблицы):

```
public class FragmentCurrentTask extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView listView;
    DBHelper db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;

    public FragmentCurrentTask() {
    }

    public static FragmentCurrentTask newInstance() {
        FragmentCurrentTask fragment = new FragmentCurrentTask();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_task, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        db.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.HEADER, DBHelper.COMMENT, DBHelper.DATE};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.headerTV, R.id.commentTV, R.id.dateTV};

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                createBrowseDialog(id);           
            }
        });

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        DBHelper db;

        MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            return db.getAllData();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }


    private void createBrowseDialog(long id) {
        /*код создания AlertDialog*/
        ...

        finishTask.setOnClickListener(new FinishTask(browseTaskDialog, id));
        browseTaskDialog.show();
    }

    private class FinishTask implements View.OnClickListener{
        AlertDialog dialog;
        long id;

        FinishTask(AlertDialog dialog, long id) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //удаление из первой таблицы и перенос во вторую
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.CURRENT_TASK_TABLE, null, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                dbHelper.addToFinished(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COMMENT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.HEADER)));
            }
            cursor.close();
            dbHelper.delete(id);
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Фрагменты отличаются лишь тем что берут данные из разных таблиц и вы создаете 2 разных фрагмента?

Comment: Рекомендую вам подумать над тем, чтобы использовать [Architecture Components в связке с `support.v7.ListAdapter`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806498/177345) (вторая половина ответа). Так ваши списки будут обновляться автоматически, в соответствии с содержимым таблиц в БД (то есть, просто удаляя запись из БД и в вашем списке она так же будет удалена автоматически).

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko в перспективе у них будет разная функциональность. На данный момент только данными из таблиц

Comment: @pavlofff а есть возможность не прибегать к сторонним библиотекам?

Comment: все это официальные библиотеки поддержки от Google, но если они вас чем то отпугивают, вы можете реализовать аналогичные функции самостоятельно (обсервер на данные и из него в RecyclerView), но я плохо понимаю мотивацию писать самому, когда есть уже готовое.

Comment: в принципе SimpleCursorAdapter тоже имеет обсервер на полученный Cursor (обновляет список автоматически при изменении курсора) - это последний аргумент в конструкторе адаптера, вместо 0 указать 1. Тогда вам нужно просто перечитывать CursorLoader и список будет обновляться

Comment: @pavlofff у меня, получается, два разных курсора в разных фрагментах. Как из первого фрагмента сообщить второму, что курсор надо обновлять?