# Удаление элемент списка RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

В моем приложении есть `RecyclerView`. Мне необходимо реализовать визуальное удаление элемента списка `RecyclerView` при нажатии на кнопку (Кнопка указана в разметке элемента списка). Как это реализовать?

Comment: Удаление из базы я уже провел, мне нужно именно что бы элемент удалился из списка визуально. Можно про removeItem(position) по подробнее?

Comment: метод адаптера для RecyclerView - [notifyItemRemoved(position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)) удалит из списка элемент по указанной позиции с анимацией.

Comment: Однако, если вы используете БД то рекомендую обратить внимание [на современные решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806498/177345) и появляющиеся с этим удобства (вторая часть ответа) - вам нужно будет только делать изменения в БД, виджет же будет обновляться сам в соответствии с актуальным состоянием БД, это очень удобно.  Вот [серия уроков](http://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html) по теме и [пример адаптера](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В адаптере  добавить Интерфейс который следит за нажатием иконки удалить.
переопределить методы что бы пожно было получить лисентер внутри активити\фрагмента

потом в активити сетаешь этот лисентер и вызови по нажатию на иконку удалить 
`adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());`

Comment: Спасибо.Разобрался.Работает