# Как обновить TextView при изменении в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Есть активность CartActivity, в котором расположен RecyclerView. Так же есть класс RecyclerViewAdapter. Для ViewHolder прописан ClickListener, где пользователю отображается AlertDialog с предложением удалить выбранный элемент из списка.

**CarActivity.java**

```
...
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                currentItem = new Item();
                currentItem.setId( cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex));
                currentItem.setName(cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex));
                currentItem.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(priceColumnIndex)));
                currentItem.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(amountColumnIndex)));
                currentItem.setImage(cursor.getString(imageColumnIndex));
                sumOrder += currentItem.getPrice()*currentItem.getAmount();
                items.add(currentItem);
            }

            mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items, R.layout.row, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            txtSumOrderView.setText(getString(R.string.txt_sum_order, sumOrder));
...
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
...
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                          (dialog, which) -> {
                                  items.remove(currentItem);
                                  notifyDataSetChanged();
                              }
                          });
                  alertDialog.show();
}
...
```

Как сказать активности, что списочный массив items с RecyclerView изменился, чтобы снова пересчитать общую сумму уже оставшихся позиций и обновить текст в элементе TextView у активности?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша архитектура использует [непродуктивное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) с копированием данных из базы в динамический список и помимо удаления из списка вам так же надо [отдельно делать удаление из базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806498/177345) (первая часть ответа, решение для `SimpleCursorAdapter` виджета `ListView`, но сама проблема думаю понятна), что еще добавляет сумбура в реализацию.

Предлагаю вам обратить внимание на последние решения в организации архитектуры взаимодействия виджетов с данными, предложенную Google - *Architecture Components*  (вторая часть ответа по ссылке выше). С появлением в библиотеке поддержки 27.1.0 класса адаптера для `RecyclerView` [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html) архитектура получила полный цикл взаимодействия и теперь любые операции с данными в БД автоматически отображаются на виджете, то есть теперь вам достаточно просто сделать записи, удаления, изменения в БД и они тут же будут отображены на экране.Естественно вам не понадобится никакое дублирование данных в списки, двойные операции по изменению данных и прочие ненужные проблемы.

Подробнее ознакомится с новой архитектурой можно по [этой серии уроков](http://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html)

Так же стоит обратить внимание на то, что вычисления с данными в БД лучше доверить самой БД, а адаптеру только заниматься непосредственно выводом на экран, а не расчетами. В данном случае вы вычисляете значение `sumOrder` в адаптере, можно доверить это БД, используя вычисляемые столбцы. Например:

```
SELECT price, count, price*count AS sum  FROM  items
```

Здесь в выборке мы получим 3 столбца: значения из столбцов *price*, *count* и вычисляемый столбец *sum* (он будет добавлен в выборку, хотя в таблице и нет такого столбца), с произведением первых двух столбцов. Теперь можно просто брать оттуда данные с нужным результатом, а не считать их в адаптере.

Comment: у realm(а) же такойже есть есть компонент (RealmAdapter), а тут его в support библиотеку добавили?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov Нет, это совершенно разные адаптеры. Первый работает с БД Realm и ее данными `RealmResult`, второй - с компонентами Architecture Components и их данными `LiveData`

Comment: я понимаю что адаптеры разные. Спасибо. Применение и результат будет одинаковым?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov Там есть свои тонкости использования, в частности обязательная реализация колбэка `DiffUtil` и получение данных в адаптере не через конструктор, а через метод `getItem()` (самому в адаптер не надо ничего передавать), но в целом да. Вы работаете с БД - список сам отображает все изменения. Вот [статья с пояснениями](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb)