# Как правильно обновить базу данных Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть три таблицы. Одна используется в качестве чтения (Tovar), две другие для манипуляций пользователем(Inventory и History).Изменяю в Sqlite  первую таблицу и добавляю новое поле и несколько новых записей. Как правильно обновить в приложение без переустановки приложения?

В пример использовался вот такие методы. Ну когда я явно вызывал этот метод, то он обновлял все данные сразу и очищает данные двух других таблиц.

```
     @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }

  private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

Что мне нужно? В таблице Tovar добавил 20 новых записей и одно новое поле (Summa), как мне отобразить эти изменения без переустановки приложения. Ведь две другие таблицы не должны изменяться и стирать данные их(Было 10 записей, они и должны остаться)

Comment: в правильно спроектированной БД не должно быть никакой надобности менять ее структуру, добавлять или удалять таблицы (за исключением случаев масштабного обновления функциональности, конечно) - это не "рядовая" процедура и требует определенной последовательности шагов. Будет лучше, если вы изложите в вопросе, зачем именно вам понадобилось это делать и есть ли в этом действительная необходимость, чем вы наделаете собственных костылей от которых будете позже страдать

Comment: @pavloff, добавил в вопросе

Comment: возможно вашу проблему можно решить не добавляя реальный, а [используя вычисляемый столбец](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809767/177345) (в конце ответа)