# Проблема с добавлением элемента в избранное во фрагменте

Tags: android

Есть `RecyclerView`, в который из готовой БД выводятся данные. Каждый отдельный элемент в `RecyclerView` имеет кнопку для добавления данной записи в избранное (`btnFavorite`). В адаптере элементы в списке имеют правильную нумерацию. Т.е. первый элемент в списке имеет `id = 1` и т.д. Проблема возникает когда я нажимаю на кнопку "Добавить в избранное", в этот момент (момент нажатия), почему-то у первого элемента списка `id <> 1`, и у других элементов тоже. Мне кажется проблема в этом и поэтому я не могу добавить элемент в избранное. Подскажите пожалуйста где у меня ошибка?

P.S. Должно работать так. При загрузке списка проверяется `id` и значение переменной `favorites` и если `favorites = true`, то иконка меняется и добавляется в избранное и наоборот.

Вот адаптер BludasAdapter

```
public class BludasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BludasAdapter.BludasViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Bludo> bludoArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Bludo> mFilteredList;
    private ItemSendId itemSendId;
    private boolean favorites;
    private int id;
    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onFavoriteButtonClick(int id, boolean isFavorite);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public class BludasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public RoundedImageView imgView;
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtIngredients;
        public ImageButton btnFavorite;

        public BludasViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imgView = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtIngredients = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredients);
            btnFavorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);

            btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnFavorite:
                    mItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonClick(id, favorites);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (itemSendId != null){
                        itemSendId.sendItemId(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    public void setItemSendId(ItemSendId itemSendId) {
        this.itemSendId = itemSendId;
    }

    public BludasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bludo> bludoArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bludoArrayList = bludoArrayList;
        this.mFilteredList = bludoArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public BludasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new BludasViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BludasViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Bludo bludo = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(bludo.getName());
        holder.txtIngredients.setText(bludo.getIngredients());

        favorites = bludo.isFavorite();
        id = bludo.getId();

        Log.d("ID = ", id + "");
        Log.d("isFavorite = ", favorites + "");

        if (favorites) {
            holder.btnFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_yellow);
        } else {
            holder.btnFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black);
        }

        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/img/" + bludo.getImage() + ".png")).into(holder.imgView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = bludoArrayList;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<Bludo> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Bludo bludo : bludoArrayList) {

                        if (bludo.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(bludo);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Bludo>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Вот код фрагмента TabFragment1

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements ItemSendId, BludasAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Bludo> bludoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView rvList;
    private BludasAdapter bludasAdapter;

    DBHelper db;

    /*AdRequest adRequesti;
    private InterstitialAd adMob;*/

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        db = new DBHelper(getContext());

        prepareBludasData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

        rvList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvList_bluda);
        bludasAdapter = new BludasAdapter(getContext(), bludoArrayList);
        bludasAdapter.setItemSendId(this);
        bludasAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
        rvList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvList.setAdapter(bludasAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
        search(searchView);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendItemId(int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BludoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(int id, boolean isFavorite) {
        String table;
        String fav;
        String toast;

        table = DBContract.Entry.TABLE_BLUDA;

        Log.d("isFavorite = ", isFavorite + "");
        Log.d("id = ", id + "");

        if (isFavorite) {
            fav = "0";
            toast = "Удалено из избранного";
        } else {
            fav = "1";
            toast = "Добавлено в избранное";
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITE, fav);
        long newRowId = db.database.update(table, values, DBContract.Entry._ID + "= " + id, null);
        if (newRowId == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void search(SearchView searchView) {

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if (bludasAdapter != null) bludasAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareBludasData() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getBludassByCategory(1);

        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME));
                    String ingridients = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_INGREDIENTS));
                    String icon = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_IMAGE));
                    String favorites = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITE));

                    bludoArrayList.add(new Bludo(id, name, ingridients, icon, favorites));
                }
            }
        }  catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: для начала подумайте [об этой проблеме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809767/177345) и откажитесь от тупиковой архитектуры пока не поздно. нет смысла решать одну проблему, когда потенциально код содержит еще множество. так же ID  не гарантирует последовательное возрастание, это идентификатор, а не порядковый номер и надеяться на то, что ID будут по порядку - верный путь к дополнительным (к первым) проблемам

Comment: если новые архитектурные решения (как Architecture Components) вас по каким то причинам не устраивают, смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) как пример реализации рабты с данными в БД - здесь есть и фильтрация и избранное и самое главное - все работает

Comment: А есть хорошие примеры статей где рассказано о новых архитектурных решениях?

Comment: А именно хотелось бы найти статью как работать с готовой БД через Room. Везде описаны примеры, где БД создается.

Comment: по ссылке в первом комментарии есть ссылка на уроки, там все есть (конкретно по Room с 5 по 13 уроки)